# nlog changes behaviour depending on logger priority

Tags: nlog

I want to log a certain layout:

```
Message: {the message}  
Properties: {key}: {value} | {key}: {value} | ...
```

My main is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Loggers.TxtLogger.LogInfo();
        Loggers.TxtLogger.LogInfo("My custom message");
        Loggers.TxtLogger.LogInfo(new { id = 1, issue = "my custom issue" });


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My Loggers class is:

```
public static class Loggers
{
    public static ILogger TxtLogger { get; private set; }

    static Loggers()
    {
        TxtLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("TxtLogger");
    }


    public static void LogInfo(this ILogger @this, object message = null)
    {
        @this.Info()
            .Property("Property1Key", "Property1Value")
            .Property("Property2Key", "Property2value")
            .Message(message == null ? "" : "{@message}", message)
            .Write();

    }

    public static void LogError(this ILogger @this, Exception e, object message = null)
    {
        @this.Error()
           .Exception(e)
           .Property("Property1Key", "Property1Value")
           .Property("Property2Key", "Property2value")
           .Message(message == null ? "" : "{@message}", message)
           .Write();
    }
}
```

My NLog.config is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

    <variable name="logFile" value="./logs/${shortdate}/${logger}.log" />

    <variable name="colon" value="${literal:text=\:}"/>
    <variable name="quotationMark" value="${literal:text=&quot;}"/>
    <variable name="messageIfNotEmpty" value="${when:when=length('${message}')>0:inner=Message${colon} ${message}${newline}}"/>
    <variable name="properties" value="Properties${colon} ${all-event-properties:format=[key]\: [value]:separator= | }${newline}"/>

    <variable name="layout2" value="${messageIfNotEmpty}${properties}"/>

    <targets>
        <target name="ConsoleLog" xsi:type="Console" layout="${layout2}"/>
        <target name="TxtLog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logFile}" layout="${layout2}"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="ConsoleLog" final="true"/>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="TxtLog" />
    </rules>

</nlog>
```

With this set i get the desired outcome:

```
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value  

Message: "My custom message"  
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value 

Message: {"id":1, "issue":"my custom issue"}  
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
```

But when I try to log it to a .txt file also (I remove the `_final="true"_` attribute from *ConsoleLog* logger), I get this outcome:

```
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value

Message: "My custom message"  
Properties: message: My custom message | Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value  

Message: {"id":1, "issue":"my custom issue"}  
Properties: message: { id = 1, issue = my custom issue } | Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
```

Now there is a work around and that's if I change the `_object message = null_` parameter in the `_LogInfo_` method to `_string message_` and I use `_newtonsoft json serializer_` to serialize the object, but I want to use the NLog serializer.
Any thoughts?

> UPDATE

At NLog.Config I changed:
`<variable name="layout2" value="${messageIfNotEmpty}${properties}"/>`
to
`<variable name="layout2" value="${properties}${messageIfNotEmpty}"/>`
(put the message variable after the properties variable)
And:
`<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="ConsoleLog" final="true"/>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="TxtLog" />
</rules>`
to
`<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="ConsoleLog"/>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="TxtLog" />
</rules>`
(removed the `final=true` attribute)

So now my Console outcome is:

```
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value

Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
Message: "My custom message"

Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
Message: {"id":1, "issue":"my custom issue"}
```

which is the desired outcome(with message after properties),
but at the txt file i get the outcome:

```
Properties: Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value

Properties: message: My custom message | Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
Message: "My custom message"

Properties: message: { id = 1, issue = my custom issue } | Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value
Message: {"id":1, "issue":"my custom issue"}
```

which obviously is not the desired outcome.

Now I change the NLog.Config once again:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="ConsoleLog"/>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="TxtLog" />
</rules>
```

to:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="TxtLog" />
    <logger name="*" writeTo="ConsoleLog"/>
</rules>
```

(I put the `TxtLog` first)
And now the outcomes are reveresed,
Console: Not the desired outcome(message is printed twice)
TXT: The desired outcome
And last if I change:

```
<variable name="layout2" value="${properties}${messageIfNotEmpty}"/>
```

back to:

```
<variable name="layout2" value="${messageIfNotEmpty}${properties}"/>
```

(put the message variable before properties),
I don't get the desired outcome whatever the logger order may be.

Comment: You have found a genuine bug in the NLog-framework, when using the NLog-Fluent-Interface together with structured logging. Which now also have been reported by you here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in NLog ver. 4.5.10 but you can work around it by changing your code to this:

```
public static class Loggers
{
    public static ILogger TxtLogger { get; private set; }

    static Loggers()
    {
        TxtLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("TxtLogger");
    }


    public static void LogInfo(this ILogger @this, object message = null)
    {
        @this.Info()
            .Message("{0}", message ?? (object)string.Empty)
            .Property("Property1Key", "Property1Value")
            .Property("Property2Key", "Property2value")
            .Write();
    }

    public static void LogError(this ILogger @this, Exception e, object message = null)
    {
        @this.Error()
           .Message("{0}", message ?? (object)string.Empty)
           .Exception(e)
           .Property("Property1Key", "Property1Value")
           .Property("Property2Key", "Property2value")
           .Write();
    }
}
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2963

Comment: When I try change the  `object message = null` to `object message = ""`, I get a compile error that reads _'message' is of type 'object'. A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null_.  Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Paying the price of writing code without help from the compiler. I have updated the code so the compiler no longer complains.

Comment: Haha we have been spoiled by the compiler indeed :P. Thanx for the work around. It works for strings but not for objects though.

Comment: @SirJeffrey Would make things easier if you explained what is not working. Did a quick test myself and logging works for all 3 LogInfo()-cases from your original question. Maybe you can update your original question about what is not working with this answer?

Comment: Sorry you are correct. I mean that it writes the message(which is an object), but also it writes it again as a property. So I get the message(object) twice recorded.

Comment: When you provide an object as a message, then it becomes part of the message. That is the structured-logging-contract. Maybe you want to use `${message:raw=true}` in the NLog.config.

Comment: I mean that at the third logger `Loggers.TxtLogger.LogInfo(new {id = 1, issue = "my custom issue"})`,  I get the result `Message: {"id":1, "issue":"my custom issue"}
Properties: message: { id = 1, issue = my custom issue } | Property1Key: Property1Value | Property2Key: Property2value`. I get the message twice that is. And as a message and as a property. Opposingly at the second logger where I pass a string as parameter I don't get the message again as a property

Comment: That is how structured logging works. You get both a message and individual properties. If you only want property then put it in property. If you only want message then stop using structured logging. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: @SirJeffrey Have now updated the answer, and removed the use of structured logging. Maybe it gives what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. So you are basically saying that if I pass an object as a message, it is automatically added as a property also. Is that so?

Comment: It is only added as a property if provided as parameter to a structured logging message-template (Ex. `{msg}` instead of `{0}`)